# How to get value from an array in vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have an array:

```
{ "id": 1, 
  "title": "Incidunt facere placeat nulla occaecati voluptatem voluptatem minus.", 
  "categories": [ 
     { "id": 1, 
      "name": "News", 
      "created_at": "2018-04-23 18:05:47", 
      "updated_at": "2018-04-23 18:05:47", 
      "pivot": { 
      "post_id": 1, 
      "category_id": 1 } }, { 
      "id": 2, 
      "name": "Sport", 
      "created_at": "2018-04-23 18:05:47", 
      "updated_at": "2018-04-23 18:05:47", 
      "pivot": { 
        "post_id": 1, 
        "category_id": 2 
        } 
       } 
     ]}
```

I can simply use `{{post.title}}` to have the post title, but when I do `{{post.categories.name}}` it returns null because its not an array.

Is there anyway to have category name?

Comment: `post.categories` is an array that can hold many categories (or none). Which name would you expect to get returned this way?

Comment: Do you have multiple item in categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Categories is an array of objects so this should work:

`{{post.categories[0].name}}` if you want the first element of categories.

Comment: @AbdelmoughitFouham don't forget to mark the answer as accepted one. You do so by clicking on the V icon at the left side.